# How to call the destroy-method for each bean in the container just before termination

Tags: java, spring

I am currently learning and experimenting around with Spring's init-method and destroy-method attributes that are specified in the spring configuration.

**My question is how can I tell Spring to call the destroy-method for those beans that have the method set, just before the program terminates?**

In other words, I wish to do any tear down operations for all beans which are attributed with a destroy-method  just before the program exists in execution. Is this even possible?

As suggested by many others, I am reading Manning's book "Spring in Action", and therefore I am experimenting with this bean for now:

```
 <bean id="auditorium" class="com.springinaction.springidol.Auditorium"
 init-method="turnOnLights"
  destroy-method="turnOffLights"/>
```

From my experiments Spring does not to this automatically and therefore, I am making use of BeanDefinitionRegistry. However, this involves implicitly removing the beans, something which I would like to avoid.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

Auditorium auditorium = (Auditorium) ctx.getBean("auditorium");

// Removing the bean from container
BeanDefinitionRegistry factory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.removeBeanDefinition("auditorium");
```

Furthermore, for the sake of a complete question, below is my Auditorium class:

```
public class Auditorium {

    private boolean isLightsOn;

    public Auditorium() {
        isLightsOn = false;
    }

    public void turnOnLights() {
        isLightsOn = true;
        printLights();
    }

    public void turnOffLights() {
        isLightsOn = false;
        printLights();
    }

    public void printLights() {
        if (isLightsOn) {
            System.out.println("Lights are turned on!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lights are turned off!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `destroy` methods are called when the context is [closed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#close%28%29) or [refreshed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29). If you run a standalone application, in order to make sure that destroy methods are called before the application ends, you need to [register a shutdown hook](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook%28%29).

All these methods are available in the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` interface, so you need to use that instead of the mere `ApplicationContext` (pretty much any context you're going to use will implement this interface so you don't need to worry):

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
ctx.registerShutdownHook(); // this should be it, destroys are called before your app exits
```

In non stand-alone (managed) scenarios like application servers, closing / refreshing the context happens automatically at shutdown / redeploy so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Cool it works..Any difference between the shutdown hook, and putting a close just before the code terminates?

Comment: Yes, the shutdown hook is more reliable; if you close your application with Ctrl-C from a terminal, the shutdown hook will get executed but your `close()` call will most likely never get reached. The shutdown hooks are what application servers usually rely on to properly terminate (unless `kill -9` cuts their head off). Ultimately, that shutdown hook for the spring app context does nothing more than call `doClose()`, but it its execution is guaranteed by the JVM.

Comment: No problem. On second thoughts, since you're experimenting, you may find the need to `close()` and `refresh()` your context without any shutdown hooks, just to track the behavior. The above recommendation is more of a production setup advice and may not be what you need for playing around.

Comment: You mention in managed scenarios the close/refresh context happens automatically.  I'm running an application in Tomcat on ElasticBeanstalk,and I'm not seeing any shutdown hooks fired at all.  All the startup ones are, but shutdown is not. I'm wondering if ElasticBeanstalk is doing some non-standard stuff when updating / redeploying.  Any ideas?

Comment: In managed scenarios like servlet containers (tomcat, in this case), you'll need to rely on the servlet context lifecycle, NOT on shutdown hooks (which would only be fired on tomcat shutdown, not on webapp redeployment). Spring provides a utility class called `ContextLoaderListener` for this purpose, which you need to configure as `<listener>` in your `web.xml`.